# Pulling a value from JSON

Tags: node.js, json

So I need to pull a value from a 3rd party website with node.js. Data is in JSON format. My code works for other similar causes but not for this one. I need to pull the price out of the according item. Data is structured in this way:

```
 {
"Glock-18 | Weasel (Battle-Scarred)": 0.52,
"PP-Bizon | Photic Zone (Minimal Wear)": 0.18,
"SSG 08 | Ghost Crusader (Field-Tested)": 0.62,
"Spectrum Case Key": 2.63,
"Sticker | shroud (Foil) | Krakow 2017": 5.62,
"Sticker | North | London 2018": 0.2,
"XM1014 | Slipstream (Field-Tested)": 0.08
}
```

My current code goes like this:

```
var Request = require("request");
var name ="Sticker | shroud (Foil) | Krakow 2017";

Request.get("url", (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }

    var object = JSON.parse(body);
    var price = object.name;
    console.log("price", price);
});
```

Any ideas why my price is always output as undefined?

Comment: Using `object.name` would assume you have an object with the property `name`, for example:  `{ "name": "something" }`

Comment: How can I pull the value out for a specific item then?

Comment: You can get the property-keys by using `var keys = Object.keys(object); `  this would return an array `["Glock-18 | Weasel (Battle-Scarred)", "PP-Bizon | Photic Zone (Minimal Wear)", ...]` Now you can use the keys to extract the values. For example: `console.log(keys[0], object[keys[0]]);`

Comment: I would convert it to an array of objects. `var arr = Object.keys(object).map(o=>({name:o,price:object[o]}));` This way you can use your method.  `var item = arr[0]; console.log(item.name, item.price);`

Comment: That works, but unfortunately I need a solution that would be able to find the value according to the name and not the index of the array.

Comment: Ah, then you can always do `var price = object["Glock-18 | Weasel (Battle-Scarred)"];` because that is the property keys (if you have the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud attempt to use `var price = object[name];` because you want to use `name` as a variable. `object.name` does not do that.

You can always troubleshoot with `console.log(object);` to convince yourself you fetched the right stuff.

For best results, consider doing error checking this way. (Never trust web sites, eh?)

```
var object;
try {
    object = JSON.parse(body);
catch (e) {
   return console.dir('body not parseable', body, e);
}
if (!object) return console.dir('no object retrieved');
if (!object.hasOwnProperty(name)) return console.dir ('property not found', name);
var price = object[name];
console.log("price", price);
```

Comment: Yep that's just what I needed. Thanks!